# Select a combobox item twice (in a row)

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, eventhandler

I am new to Java so I apologise in advance if my code is bad.

I have a combobox with listener

```
myCombobox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        myMethod();
    }
});


public void myMethod() {
    try {
        value = myCombobox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();
        logger.info( "value: " + value );
        int id = myCombobox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        logger.info( "id: " + id );

        model.setSavedRequestID(id);
        model.setSavedRequestContent(id);

        // saved=id;
        hostCmbBox.getSelectionModel().select(developmentTopPanelModel.getHost());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

A user can select an item from the combobox, text for this item is then displayed in a text area.  The user can then modify this text in the text area which is the functionality that is needed.  But if the user wants to go back to the original text they select the SAME item again in the combobox but because this item is already selected nothing happens.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What API is this based on? Swing, AWT, SWT, Android?

Comment: About the only way I can see you getting around this is to replace the `selectionModel` so you can intercept the point of change and allow duplicate values to raise events...

Comment: @MadProgrammer would you have any sample code to show me what you mean - sorry really new to this

Comment: It seems to me that when the user changes the text in the text area, you should change the selected item in the combo box (possibly to a new item, representing the new text). That would both solve the problem and make the UI more consistent with the underlying data.

Comment: @James_D thanks for this suggestion - is this possible when the text area and the combobox are in two different controllers?

Comment: Sure. There are many questions here on SO about sharing data between controllers.